# How to say "and such" in German?

Tags: translation, english-to-german

I'd like to translate the sentence "We need sunburn cream, bath towels and such."

> Wir werden heute an den Strand fahren. Was brauchen wir fürs Sonnenliegen?
>
> Wir brauchen Sonnebrand-Creme, Badetücher und oder so.

Comment: Just remove the `oder`. Its `und so`.

Comment: "und so was" oder "und dergleichen" bzw. "und so weiter" ginge ebenfalls.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The most colloquial way is the one suggested in the other answer

> ... und so (was).

But there are several other versions that are more suitable for print.

> ... und solcherlei Dinge.

A bit overcomplicated, might work in novels or texts that make use of all the language has to offer. I can see that in a comedic text for instance.

> ... und dererlei Dinge.

Same as above but even more high brow and it doesn't have the least bit of a wink to it (solcherlei has). I can see that in literature.

> ... und dergleichen.

That is maybe the most neutral choice for print. It is not as mundane as *und so* but it lacks the "ornamentiness" of the other two.

Comment: "and such" has a kind of old fashioned sound to it which is perfectly matched by "und dergleichen".

Answer (score 4):

RienNeVaPlus above is right: It's just

> Wir brauchen Sonnencreme, Badetücher und so.

Sonnenbrand-Creme sounds strange. And instead of "Sonnenliegen" use "Sonnenbaden".

Answer (score 2):

"and such" is more specific than "und so". the latter one doesn't refer to a similar type of items, while the former does.

> Wir sollten Sonnencreme, Badetücher und solcherlei mitnehmen.

Comment: IMO, "und so" does refer to a similar type of items. I think it's a short form of "und so etwas".

Comment: sure a short form, but 'so etwas' is still different from 'solcherlei' or 'derartig'. _persoanlly, i consider 'und so' as an expression of lazyness, i.e. to think :)_

Answer (score 2):

(Being German) I can say that "*und solcherlei*" is definitely wrong!
Common idioms are "*und so*" or "*und sowas*" as well as the abbreviations "*etc.*" and "*usw.*" (the latter means "und so weiter").

A slang/sloppy version could also be:

> "Wir brauchen Sonnencreme, Badetücher *und so'n Kram*" (or "... *und so'n Zeug*").

"... *und dergleichen*" is neutral and could be used in written text, while still being OK for direct speech.